# How to detect (in Hibernate) when the database goes down?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

We are using Hibernate to connect to MySQL database. Need a way to get an alert when the database goes down. Was reading about the listeners in Hibernate but not sure if any one of them can be used to detect database-down event.

Comment: You'd only know the db was down if you tried to do something (like get an entity) and it failed.  The exception would be dependent on things like what connection pooling you're using (if any).  Best bet, imo, is to take down the db and see what exceptions you get in your app and try to work with those.

Comment: Catch org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException

Comment: Catching exception is certainly one of the options, but I wanted a cleaner way. I mean, getting an alert when the database goes down.

Comment: Doesn't the exception itself count as an alert? If not, I don't know what is.

Comment: Exception may occur only where there's some db activity.

Comment: And that will always be that way if you don't poll the connection every now and then somehow. Don't expect the database to notify you it is down when... it is down :)

Comment: Right, that's what I was wondering if Hibernate has any feature which does this polling and fires an event when it finds the database down. Else I will have to do it anyway in my code.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Bart in the comments above, tried to achieve the functionality through the following code. Please feel free to suggest any improvements or alternatives.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException;

public class PollingThread extends Thread {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PollingThread.class);
private long interval;

public PollingThread() {
    // default polling interval set to 5 seconds
    this(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5));
}

public PollingThread(final long interval) {
    this.interval = interval;
    this.setDaemon(true);
    LOGGER.debug("Polling thread initialized!");
}

@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {
        boolean connected = poll();
        LOGGER.debug("Connected - " + connected);

        if (!connected) {
            // TODO connect to fail-over database
        }

        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                wait(interval);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                LOGGER.warn("Polling thread interrupted", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean poll() {

    boolean connected = true;
    try {
        final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        final Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    } catch (JDBCConnectionException ex) {
        connected = false;
    }

    return connected;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new PollingThread());
}
}
```